# What is this Union Jack with a "QR" inscription in the Lego Ninjago movie?

Tags: lego, lego-cinematic-universe, the-lego-ninjago-movie

I see it a lot in the scene where they are in their HQ and when Nya is talking to Lloyd but I don't know what it means or what it is?

It somewhat appears to be spinoff of the British Flag.

[image: flag seen in movie]

Comment: Or in Latin Quintus Rex meaning King Quintus?